# Android adb sort of works but can't load to device

Tags: android

I have a zenithink zt-180 tablet connected to my usb port. I can use adb (from the command line) to get a shell command, reboot the tablet, and stuff like that, though I do have to kill and start the server first on the initial connect.

I can also run ddms and it shows me the device threads and statistics and so forth for the tablet.

However, whenever I try to load the helloAndroid example adb and ddms hang. To recover I have to cntr-C out of them, kill the server and then start the server. I can then do the above stated operations, just not load. In Eclips I get an error saying "failed to install HelloAndroid on device 0123456.... : timeout when i try to debug on the device.

I know the application can run because I loaded it onto a USB stick and installed it on the tablet. It ran fine.

What is it about the load program command that is hanging up adb???

Note: USB debugging is enabled in the device. I make sure that only one DDMS and adb are running. All eclips components and the USB driver were loaded two days ago. The tablet is running android 2.1.1

Comment: Have you tried to use the command "adb install"?

Comment: Yes. When I mention installing from the command line that is the command I am using. It hangs adb, and then the server needs to be killed and re-started.

Comment: does "adb devices" list your device? If not then connectivity is the issue.

Comment: the only thing that adb says is 12345678910ABC sort of thing and then it tells me the device is online. I don;t think it's a connectivity issue though because I can reboot the tablet, open a shell and ddms can even see individual processes running and report statistics.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the server. That's why i have to kill and then restart the server every time it hangs. Does anyone know how to debug the protocol of the stream? Is there a log file? Can I watch it in real time in ddms?

Comment: I have a ZT-180. How can I get Honeycomb 3.2 firmware for ZT-180 and Install ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So I did not really fix this but I did find a work around and it's better then USB cable.

Connect to the tablet via the USB cable and issue the adb command "adb tcpip 5555". This command executed and did not crash my adb server. This is key.

Next use the connect command to connect via tcpip.

adb connect :5555

I had firmware 1030 on the ZT-180. Note: I did not have to install adbwireless and I did not have to root it.

credit to the person who came up with these directions: http://www.slatedroid.com/index.php?topic=4316.0

Thanks to all who tried to help

Answer (score 0):

I have had this same effect from a defective USB cable. adb connected just fine, got the prompt on the phone to trust the computer, the device showed up as online when listing adb devices, but any attempt at install whether from the IDE or from the command line caused adb to just hang. Try a different cable.